# Handling Unique Values by Column

Tags: r, unique

[image: The Data Frame Sample]

So I have the above dataframe, I am trying to get a data frame with all the unique da_rec and their appropriate values. I have tried using `unique()` and `!duplicated`.

What I want is:

[image: Need]

What else can I do?

Reproducible code:

```
test = data.frame(da_rec = c("2016-04-01", "2016-04-01", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-05", "2016-04-06", "2016-04-07", "2016-04-08",
"2016-04-08", "2016-04-11", "2016-04-11", "2016-04-12", "2016-04-12", "2016-04-13", "2016-04-14",
"2016-04-15", "2016-04-15", "2016-04-18", "2016-04-19", "2016-04-19", "2016-04-20", "2016-04-20",
"2016-04-21", "2016-04-21", "2016-04-22", "2016-04-25", "2016-04-26", "2016-04-26", "2016-04-27",
"2016-04-27", "2016-04-28", "2016-04-28", "2016-04-29", "2016-04-29"), values = c(NA,  1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  
1, NA,  1, NA,  2, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA,  3, NA,  1, NA,  1, NA, NA, NA,  2, NA,  1, NA,  2, NA, 3))
```

Comment: If the `NA`s are always in the end, you can just specify `fromLast = TRUE` and then `!duplicated` should work as in `test[!duplicated(test$da_rec, fromLast = TRUE), ]`

Comment: Hey man ya this didn't work as the NA's weren't only at the end

Comment: So just reorder first.

Comment: I just used the answer below it worked perfectly, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't want unique values, you want to remove NAs when there's an existing value.

The way you can do it is take all your unique date values on one hand, and a subset of your data without NAs on the other hand, and merge them together.  R will complete missing values with NAs.

```
merge(data.frame(da_rec = unique(test$da_rec)),
      subset(test,!is.na(values)),
      all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot man it worked, I spent a good hour trying to figure that out.